# How to loop through children of querySelectorAll matches

Tags: javascript

I want to update all child nodes of elements that match a certain attribute using querySelectorAll, but when I loop through the children of the current match, it breaks the loop.

For example when I do the following:

```js
var allElements = document.querySelectorAll("[class]");
for (var i = 0; i < allElements.length; i++) {
    var element = allElements[i];
    element.style.color = "red";
}
```

```html
<div class="test1">
  <div>Child 1</div>
  <div>Child 2</div>
</div>

<div class="test2">
  <div>Child 3</div>
  <div>Child 4</div>
</div>

<div class="test3">
  <div>Child 3</div>
  <div>Child 4</div>
</div>
```

I get all each matching element

But when I then loop through the children of each match I only get the first match.

```js
var allElements = document.querySelectorAll("[class]");
for (var i = 0; i < allElements.length; i++) {
    var element = allElements[i];

    for (i = 0; i < element.children.length; i++) {
        var child = element.children[i];
        console.log(child)
    }
  
    element.style.color = "red";
}
```

```html
<div class="test1">
  <div>Child 1</div>
  <div>Child 2</div>
</div>

<div class="test2">
  <div>Child 3</div>
  <div>Child 4</div>
</div>

<div class="test2">
  <div>Child 3</div>
  <div>Child 4</div>
</div>
```

Can someone help me understand why this happens and how I get around it? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

because you have used `i` variable in both loop so loop key length `2` reset due to children DOM element have 2 length, you should another variable like `j` in inner loop then work fine

```js
var allElements = document.querySelectorAll("[class]");
for (var i = 0; i < allElements.length; i++) {
  var element = allElements[i];

  for (var j = 0; j < element.children.length; j++) {
    var child = element.children[i];
    console.log(child)
  }

  element.style.color = "red";
}
```

```html
<div class="test1">
  <div>Child 1</div>
  <div>Child 2</div>
</div>

<div class="test2">
  <div>Child 3</div>
  <div>Child 4</div>
</div>

<div class="test2">
  <div>Child 3</div>
  <div>Child 4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. That explains a lot. :)

Answer (score 2):

You are using same variable in both loop. Use different

```
for (j = 0; j < element.children.length; j++) {
    var child = element.children[j];
    console.log(child)
  }
```

Comment: Of course, thank you for spotting that for me. I've been going insane over this.

Answer (score 0):

```
var allElements = document.querySelectorAll("[class]");
for (i = 0; i < allElements.length; i++) {
    var element = allElements[i];

    for (i = 0; i < element.children.length; i++) {
        var child = element.children[i];
        console.log(child)
    }

    element.style.color = "red";
}
```

You reassigned value of `i` inside the inner for loop.

```
var allElements = document.querySelectorAll("[class]");
for (var i = 0, j=0; i < allElements.length; i++) {
    var element = allElements[i];

    for (; j < element.children.length; j++) {
        var child = element.children[j];
        console.log(child)
    }

    element.style.color = "red";
}
```